# flutter: HIToolbox NSApplicationMain + 817 error when switching window on VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this annoying erro that appears in the debugger of vs code, but not xcode.

This is for flutter, using stable channel 3.7.0

The debug error appears every time I switch focus from VS Code, to the App and back. It's making it hard to debug with the constant scrolling.

Any thoughts on a solution? Other than to use XCode :) Also, this debug error appears on macos and on windows.

`Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (3 weeks ago) • 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800 Engine • revision b24591ed32 Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1`

```
1   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812d1b726 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 102
2   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cbf852 SetMenuBarObscured + 226
3   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cbf4ca _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 164
4   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cb9996 _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 252
5   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812c81bd2 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 153
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff80c69e213 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 3212
7   AppKit                              0x00007ff80c6146ae -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2595
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff80c613a6f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 345
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff80c611dde -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 358
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c8d0885 -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 65
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c4a141c -[NSApplication run] + 623
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c475427 NSApplicationMain + 817
13  bible_breeze                        0x00000001034e0969 main + 9
14  dyld                                0x00007ff808f57310 start + 2432
1   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812ca80c2 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22RemoveAutoShowObserverEv + 30
2   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cbf7e3 SetMenuBarObscured + 115
3   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cc629e _ZN13HIApplication11FrontUILostEv + 34
4   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cbf622 _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 508
5   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cb9950 _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 182
6   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812c81bd2 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 153
7   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812cb93e6 AcquireEventFromQueue + 494
8   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812ca85a4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 725
9   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff812ca82b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c4aff33 _DPSNextEvent + 909
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c4aedb4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c4a13f7 -[NSApplication run] + 586
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff80c475427 NSApplicationMain + 817
14  bible_breeze                        0x00000001034e0969 main + 9
15  dyld                                0x00007ff808f57310 start + 2432
```